# How to inset faces down to edges rather than faces

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to inset faces so that I end up with a row of edges along the faces, so that I get something like this:

[image]

Here of course I just get a really thin row of faces, when I wanted edges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to make an edge in the middle:

Simple process: <kbd>i</kbd> >> <kbd>1</kbd> >> <kbd>Enter</kbd> >> <kbd>W</kbd> >> **Remove Doubles**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please don't scale too close. Just scale a little.

Than select both Vertices and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and select **At Center**

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]